# How to deploy multiple instances of the same stackset in the same AWS account and region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, multi-tenant, aws-sam

I am creating a multi tenant architecture. I need to duplicate my recources whenever a new tenant registers my platform.

I created a stackset in my SAM project like this:

```
StackSet:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::StackSet
    Properties:
      Capabilities:
        - "CAPABILITY_IAM"
        - "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"
        - "CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND"
      AdministrationRoleARN: !GetAtt AdministrationRole.Arn
      ExecutionRoleName: !Ref ExecutionRole
      OperationPreferences:
        FailureToleranceCount: 0
        MaxConcurrentCount: 1
      PermissionModel: 'SELF_MANAGED'
      StackInstancesGroup:
        - DeploymentTargets:
            Accounts: 
              - !Ref AWS::AccountId
          Regions: 
            - !Ref AWS::Region
        - DeploymentTargets:
            Accounts: 
              - !Ref AWS::AccountId
          Regions: 
            - !Ref AWS::Region
      Tags:
        - 
          Key: 'PROJECT'
          Value: 'imaclegal'
      StackSetName: 'imaclegal'
      TemplateURL: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/a-child-s3/output.yaml'
```

When I execute `sam deploy` I get this error:

> Properties validation failed for resource StackSet   with message: #:
> #: only 1 subschema matches out of 2  #/StackInstancesGroup: array items are not unique

So it seems I can not get to deploy more than 1 instance in the same AWS account and region, is there any way to accomplish multiple instances in the same AWS account and region? Or is there any other better way to duplicate my resources for my new tenants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep all resources in a single account/region, CloudFormation StackSets currently won't do what you need.
If your resources aren't named within your template, you could just create multiple CloudFormation stacks. This could get messy to maintain though, and you're more likely to hit service quotas if you're running the applications at scale.

Personally, I recommend using AWS Organizations to create an account for each tenant. CloudFormation StackSets can then be used to automatically duplicate your resources to new accounts.

This solution also has the added benefit of more precise cost-allocation for each tenant.